# postgis is not working after the installation of GDAL in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: postgresql, postgis, gdal

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 with the psql (PostgreSQL 10.17)

```
dpkg -l | grep postgis
ii  postgis                                    3.0.1+dfsg-2~bionic0                             amd64        Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL
ii  postgis-doc                                3.0.1+dfsg-2~bionic0                             all          Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL -- documentation
ii  postgresql-10-postgis-2.5-scripts          2.5.2+dfsg-1~bionic1                             all          Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 10 -- SQL scripts
ii  postgresql-10-postgis-3                    3.0.1+dfsg-2~bionic0                             amd64        Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 10
ii  postgresql-10-postgis-3-scripts            3.0.1+dfsg-2~bionic0                             all          Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 10 -- SQL scripts
server@server-B250M-D3H:~$
```

I am using postgis enabled postgesql for my application development and it was working fine. Then I installed python GDAL version 3.0.4  but after that psql show error as below,

ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.5": No such file or directory

I have removed postgis and postgresql and re-installed all the associated packages and given the query

CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

but shows same error again.
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.5": No such file or directory

how to solve this error.

Comment: do you need both postgis 2.5 and 3.0?

Comment: no I want latest only

Comment: Have you tried `apt remove postgresql-10-postgis-2.5-scripts` and then `CREATE EXTENSION` again? It seems postgres is trying to install the older version  of postgis (the one you don't need)

Comment: I have removed the postgresql-10-postgis-2.5-scripts and  tried "CREATE EXTENSION postgis; "
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory

Comment: Ok, at least a different error message.. sounds like progress :) Can you reinstall postgis 3.0 and try create extension again? I suspect the `apt-remove` also deleted the control file from the version 3.0

Comment: re-installed postgresql-10-postgis-3.  No change.